# Timeout error, but answer posted anyway?

Tags: bug, ios-app, ipad

I'm on 3G with good signal, and version 1.1.0.131

When replying to a question with a fairly short (two paragraph) answer, the app hung after hitting submit. I eventually got bored and clicked back, then went to reply again and resumed the draft, I submitted again and again waited as the app did nothing. Eventually I got a timeout message and the app jumped back to the question, but did post the answer

Comment: I've seen this in sketchy network conditions (not the signal to the cell tower, but when the cell tower itself has load issues communicating with the internet in general) on iPhone before several times. I was frankly surprised how well the app saved the draft and carried out the post despite not getting confirmation back that the post was successful.

Comment: It did seem to handle the situation fairly well, but I certainly don't seem to be experiencing any network issues on any other app or Internet use on either my iPad or iPhone - the connection has been rock solid for months

Comment: I suppose difficulty on the API end could cause it as well. If it's a bug, more people will likely see it and up vote. I was in a remote area recently and had the "pleasure" of noticing how good my network usually is.